# Random Sobol 3D Cell in Unity

Tags: unity, random

There is a blueprint in UE4 for making Sobol random 3D cell. It places random objects inside cell structure.
How to make this in Unity?

For example, if I make a sphere prefab I would need to generate Sobol distribution in some volume.

[image]

EDIT:

@Seyed Morteza Kamali have made a script:

[image]
[image]

Comment: try this [Random.insideUnitSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitSphere.html).to spawning an object Inside a cube you can generate random xyz.also you can use mesh bounds like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/134801/70732)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Mesh bounds` to generating inside the bounding volume of the mesh.

> The bounding volume of the mesh.
>
> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html

Attach this script to your cube:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomInside : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Prefab;
    public int Number = 50;
    public float Factor = 0.5f;

    void Start () {
        for (int i = 0; i <= Number; i++)
        {
        var obj = Instantiate(Prefab,GetRandomPosInsideTheMesh(),Quaternion.identity);
        obj.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        }
    }

public Vector3 GetRandomPosInsideTheMesh(){
    Mesh mesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    Bounds bounds = mesh.bounds;
    var pos = transform.position;
    var scale = transform.localScale;
    float minX = pos.x - scale.x * bounds.size.x * Factor;
    float minY = pos.y - scale.y * bounds.size.y * Factor;
    float minZ = pos.z - scale.z * bounds.size.z * Factor;

    Vector3 RandomArea = new Vector3(Random.Range (minX, -minX),
                                 Random.Range (minY, -minY),
                                 Random.Range (minZ, -minZ));
    return RandomArea;
}
}
```

Comment: it works! I've put images in first post. Thank you!